# Helm - How to add a label block through values.yaml

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have simple helm chart. I have a `labels:` block that I need to refer in a `Deployment`

Here's my `values.yaml`

```
labels:
    app: test-app
    group: test-group
    provider: test-provider
```

And in the `templates/deployment.yaml` I need to add the above whole `labels` block. So I did;

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "accountmasterdata.fullname" . }}
  namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
  labels:
  {{ .Values.labels | nindent 4 }}

  {{- include "accountmasterdata.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
```

But I get the following error

> wrong type for value; expected string; got map[string]interface {}

Can someone help me with two things:

1. How can I solve this issue
2. And in the line where it says `{{- include "accountmasterdata.labels" . | nindent 4 }}` , where I can see the `accountmasterdata.labels` values? And how to override those?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating over a mapping is covered in the "[Variables](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/variables/)" documentation:

> For data structures that have both a key and a value, we can use range to get both. For example, we can loop through .Values.favorite like this:
>
> ```
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: ConfigMap
> metadata:
>   name: {{ .Release.Name }}-configmap
> data:
>   myvalue: "Hello World"
>   {{- range $key, $val := .Values.favorite }}
>   {{ $key }}: {{ $val | quote }}
>   {{- end }}
> ```

So in your template, you would handle the value of `.Values.labels` like this:

```
  labels:
{{- range $name, $value := .Values.labels }}
    {{ $name | quote }}: {{ $value | quote }}
{{- end -}}
```

---

> And in the line where it says {{- include "accountmasterdata.labels" . | nindent 4 }} , where I can see the accountmasterdata.labels values? And how to override those?

Is this a template you are writing? If so, where have you defined these values? Presumably in your `templates/` directory there exists a file that includes something like:

```
{{- define "accountmasterdata.labels" -}}
...
{{- end -}}
```

The contents of that block are what will get inserted at the point of reference.

---

Lastly, in your template you have:

```
namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}
```

But you probably want to use `.Release.Namespace` instead:

```
namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace | quote }}
```

---

With the above changes in place, I end up with:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "accountmasterdata.fullname" . }}
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace | quote }}
  labels:
{{- range $name, $value := .Values.labels }}
    {{ $name | quote }}: {{ $value | quote }}
{{- end -}}
{{- include "accountmasterdata.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
```